# how react can return a tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i just want to read a very starter peace of code in react:

```
return (
    <blob></blob>
)
```

but i can't handle this in my mind at all ! how this is possible in react? shouldn't something like this make an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` in javascript ??

can somebody help me to understand how react works and deal with this pure javascript error which should happen when javascript tries to compile/interpret(javpile!) it?

**i know what is JSX!, but i mean that we are putting javascript rules underfoot with this**

Comment: This is what jsx is. Read more about this. You will get context of this

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in plain javascript that would return an error. If you copy and paste something like that in a browser console, an expection will be thrown.

That's why you can't directly include jsx files in a browser, but you need to use some kind of preprocessor (like webpack, babel etc..) configured to use a plugin able to understand jsx and translate it into a js file.

Usually:

```
.js -> browser
```

With react:

```
.jsx -> preprocessor with proper configuration -> .js -> browser
```